# クローズ理由の選択画面で、重複している質問先の入力欄が見切れている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

### 不具合事象

クローズ理由の選択画面で、重複している質問先の入力欄が見切れています。以下が問題のスクリーンショットで、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下が問題を改善した後のスクリーンショットです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ブラウザのバージョンなど)

不具合が再現した OS, ブラウザは以下のとおりです。

- Windows 7, Windows 10
- Google Chrome 74.0.3729.131
- Opera 60.0.3255.59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現在、この問題は無くなっています。デザイン変更に伴ない直ったものと思われます。

> [image: スクリーンショット]